# IPV4 Lan 2 IPs remove 169.254.* from nic

Tags: windows-7, networking, ip, ipv4

[image]When I ipconfig:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.30.2.194
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 169.254.47.101
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.30.2.1
```

How do i remove the second entry of IPv4, its confusing some process on my computer, And why is is there?

Thanks.

Comment: When you have both an address from a DHCP server and a 169.254 zeroconf address it usually indicates an IP conflict with the primary address.  In other words, there's a reasonable chance that there is another device on your network with the 172.30.2.194 address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a 169.254 address is a link-local IPv4 Zero-conf networking address. its often a fallback in the case that a DHCP server cannot be found, but it is also used by some client/server protocols like UPNP, ITunes sharing, windows Media homegroup stuff, and some other 1-click LAN sharing protocols.

if you have any clients that use zero-conf networking, uninstall them, and the IP shoudl disappear unless you fail to contact a DHCP server at lease renewal time.

see here: http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/sep/24/169-254-0-0-addresses-explained/
http://www.macgasm.net/2009/03/22/bonjour/

Comment: +1 This seems correct. Maybe he has a dual port network card and one port configured with a static IP entry 172.30.2.194 and the second one uses DHCP which can't be contacted. So the default fallback IP 169.254.47.101 is generated.

Comment: how can i remove this ? i un-installed all my lately install application. who added it ? how can i detect? thanks

Comment: Windows always adds there link-local 169.254.x.x addresses when you configured the interface for automatic configuration and it doesn't get an IPv4 address from a DHCP server. You can disable the interface if you don't need it, or you can configure a static address. It doesn't do any harm though, so you might as well just leave it there...

Comment: Right click on the network interface and then click Properties.  Double click TCP/IP V4 

Click the Alternate Configuration tab.  Is there an IP address shown?

Comment: did not find such tab. but its ok now the other address was removed once setting a static ip. thank you all. and my process works now. thanks alot for ipv4 for wasting 2 hours of my time :)

Comment: have you disabled the MS SSDP services? IIRC thats their UPNP service host.